Highlighting the matching time
For say I have a table of 2 columns  names , date and time how can I highlight the names in which the difference between their date and times is equal or less than 10 hours in redash I tired hour and timediff didnt work
function that works with redash



Name
date




Claire
2025-05-25, 16:13:43


mona
2025-05-25, 21:13:43


engy
2025-05-26, 23:13:43




Please update your question with sample data, the result you are trying to achieve and the code you've managed to write so far. All as editable text, appropriately formatted. Thanks

Ok - so I assume that’s your source data? You still need to show the result you expect from this source data and the code you’ve managed to write so far
